# How to receive a message through TCPBasicClientApp in omnet++?

Tags: tcp, tcpclient, omnet++

I have made two different TCP Applications in Omnet++, one is `TCPBasicClientApp` and other is `TCPGenericServerApp`. TCP client application is successfully sending a `GenericAppMsg` through TCP Protocol. Once the message is received on the Server Side (with a specific `replyLength`) it is sending it back to the client side through `SendBack()` method (also mentioned in the inet example application).

My question is, how to receive this message back on the client side?

Here is the omnet.ini file code, for this transfer,

The Client Side,

```
**.host[0].numTcpApps = 1
**.host[0].tcpApp[0].typename = "ReputationAlgorithmApplication"
**.host[0].tcpApp[0].localAddress = ""
**.host[0].tcpApp[0].localPort = -1
**.host[0].tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "host[3]"
**.host[0].tcpApp[0].connectPort = 2000
**.host[0].tcpApp[0].dataTransferMode = "object"
```

The Server Side,

```
**.host[3].numTcpApps = 1
**.host[3].tcpApp[*].typename = "ReputationServerApplication"
**.host[3].tcpApp[*].localAddress = "host[3]"
**.host[3].tcpApp[*].localPort = 2000
```

Here is the sendBack method on Server Side,

```
void ReputationServerApplication::sendBack(cMessage *msg) {
    cPacket *packet = dynamic_cast<cPacket *>(msg);

    if (packet) {
        msgsSent++;
        bytesSent += packet->getByteLength();
        emit(sentPkSignal, packet);

        EV_INFO << "sending \"" << packet->getName() << "\" to TCP, "
                       << packet->getByteLength() << " bytes\n";
    } else {
        EV_INFO << "sending \"" << msg->getName() << "\" to TCP\n";
    }
    DummyMessageForReputation *msgDum =
            dynamic_cast<DummyMessageForReputation *>(msg);
    std::cout << "\n Tested: Message with the string "
            << msgDum->getMessageString() << " is sending back to "
            << msgDum->getNodeName();

    send(msgDum, "tcpOut");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TCPBasicClientApp::socketDataArrived()` to process the received message on the client side.

Comment: Yes that is what i did, but the problem here is that it is not receiving from every node. So here is the situation, i have a Wireless Mesh Network of 10 nodes... five nodes, send other five nodes a message, and the recipient should take the message and reply back the same message to the sender. I am able to retrieve 3 messages out of 5 with SocketDataArrived().

For some reason, the messages from the two nodes are sending back from the receiver but can't be acquired at the socketDataArrived().

Comment: Many reasons can lead this problem because of wireless environment, such as packet collision, or the received SNR is not satisfied the radio requirement, and so on. Could you please use step mode to find which module the packet discarded, and then debug the source code line by line to find the problem exactly?

Comment: Debugging the code line by line is almost impossible for me because i am using Omnet++ on Mac OSX Yosemite and there is no gdb version available for this, hence no debugging! It would be no problem if i could debug.

I agree with you that many reason can led to this problem, but i am not moving nodes positions and also every node is in the range of every other node. The only reason that i can think of is the packet collision, may be i need to tweak some wireless parameters for this.

Thank you for your help.